# Generate HTML to PDF, and upload generated PDF to storage (laravel) (Dompdf Library)

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I want to use `storeAs()` but it doesn't work (Dompdf library)

How to put the converted PDF file in storage ?

```php
$data = ['discription' => 'tifa']; 

$pdf = PDF::loadView('file.viewFile', compact('data'))->storeAs("public/uploud",'filename');

return $pdf->stream("file.pdf");`
```

Comment: Are you using `laravel-dompdf` or just `dompdf`?

Comment: There is a typo in `->storeAs("public/uploud,'filename');` where you lack a quote `"`.

Comment: i'm using laravel-dompdf

Comment: sorry about the quote  but still i don't know how to store it in the storage

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = ['discription'=>'tifa']; 
  $pdf =PDF::loadView('file.viewFile',compact('data'));
    $content = $pdf->output();
       $x= storage_path("app/public/uploud/anyname.pdf");
      file_put_contents($x, $content);

      return $pdf->stream(" anyname.pdf");
```